# What is the difference between Ruby's send and public_send methods?

Tags: ruby

I am very curious to know what the difference is between `send` and `public_send`. E.g.:

```
class Klass
  def hello(*args)
    "Hello " + args.join(' ')
  end
end

k = Klass.new
k.send :hello, "gentle", "readers" #=> "Hello gentle readers"
k.public_send :hello, "gentle", "readers" #=> "Hello gentle readers"
```

Comment: To see what @Casper means, make your `hello` method private and try again.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> Unlike send, public_send calls public methods only.

[Source](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send)

Example:

```
class Klass
  private
  def private_method
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

k = Klass.new
k.send(:private_method)
# => "Hello"

k.public_send(:private_method)
# => `public_send': private method `private_method' called for #<Klass:0x007f5fd7159a80> (NoMethodError)
```

You may want to prefer `#public_send` over `#send` so as not to circumvent private/protected visibility.