# Refer to a method with varying name

Tags: ruby

I'd like to know how to call a method with a varying name. I have:

```
queries = ['new_teachers']
```

I'd like to call the method `new_teachers` on a module `DailyQueries` using a reference to the array element like `DailyQueries[queries[i]]`, which should be equivalent to `DailyQueries.new_teachers`. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `public_send` method to call an arbitrary method on an object. For  example, `foo.public_send(:bar)` is equivalent to `foo.bar`, and works exactly the same way.

Knowing this you can define an array of symbols, where each symbol is a method you want to call. So:

```
[:bar, :baz, :qorg].each {|method|
  DailyQueries.public_send(method)
end
```

will work the same as:

```
DailyQueries.bar
DailyQueries.baz
DailyQueries.qorg
```

Here's some reading material if you'd like to learn more about the `public_send` method, and its less privacy-respecting cousin, the `send` method:

- [What is the difference between ruby send and ruby public_send method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401970/what-is-the-difference-between-ruby-send-and-ruby-public-send-method)
- [What does send() do in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337285/what-does-send-do-in-ruby)
- [Object#public_send on RubyDoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send)

Comment: It's not quite the same since send ignores method visibility (private, protected) - consider using `public_send`

Comment: Thanks @FrederickCheung. I have updated the answer per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just a way to call a method if a variable has method name string, then, refer to @sawa's answer.  If, for some specific reason, you need to invoke a module method using `[]` syntax, then, read on.

---

If you say method is part of module, then, it must be its singleton method as shown below, only then, you can invoke it using `DailyQueries.new_teachers` syntax

```
module DailyQueries
  def self.new_teachers
    ["A", "B"]
  end
end
```

You cannot invoke module methods using `[]` syntax - hence, you may have to add a method to module that does this for you.

```
module DailyQueries
  def self.[] name, *params
    method(name)[*params]
  end
  #... other methods definitions
end
```

Now, you can do this:

```
DailyQueries[queries[0]]
```

If the method had any parameters, you can pass arguments as:

```
DailyQueries[queries[0], "param1", "param2", :another_param]
```

Comment: You could also define an alias: `class << self ; alias_method :[], :public_send ; end`

Answer (score -2):

```
DailyQueries.send(queries[i])
```

....................

Comment: While technically correct, your answer does not explain why your solution works. Think about how you can make your answer more useful instead of padding it with garbage.

Comment: @JustinHoward Legend has that sawa does not spend more than few microseconds to answer questions using his [HHK](http://www.amazon.com/Happy-Hacking-Keyboard-Professional2-Black/dp/B000EXZ0VC) :D