# When to use send and public_send methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby

`send` can be used to call public as well as private methods.

Example:

```
class Demo
  def public_method
    p "public_method" 
  end

  private

  def private_method
    p "private_method" 
  end
end

Demo.new.send(:private_method)
Demo.new.send(:public_method)
```

Then where and why to use `public_send`?

Comment: My question is if send can call public as well as private method then when and why to use public_send?

Comment: AFAIK `send` exists since the first version of ruby, but `public_send` is introduced quite late in order to meet the taste of those who prefer strict encapsulation.

Comment: Use `public_send` when you intend to call public methods and are not trying to mess with internals. This way you communicate your intent to future readers of your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Ruby's send and public\_send methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401970/what-is-the-difference-between-rubys-send-and-public-send-methods)

Answer (score 20):

Use `public_send` when you want to dynamically infer a method name and call it, yet still don't want to have encapsulation issues.

In other words, `public_send` will only simulate the call of the method directly, no work arounds. It's good for mixing encapsulation and meta programming.

Example:

```
class MagicBox
  def say_hi
    puts "Hi"
  end

  def say_bye
    puts "Bye"
  end

  private

  def say_secret
    puts "Secret leaked, OMG!!!"
  end

  protected

  def method_missing(method_name)
    puts "I didn't learn that word yet :\\"
  end
end

print "What do you want met to say? "
word = gets.strip

box = MagicBox.new
box.send("say_#{word}")        # => says the secret if word=secret
box.public_send("say_#{word}") # => does not say the secret, just pretends that it does not know about it and calls method_missing.
```

When the input is `hi` and `secret` this is the output:

```
What do you want met to say? hi
=> Hi
=> Hi

What do you want met to say? secret
=> Secret leaked, OMG!!!
=> I didn't learn that word yet :\\
```

As you can see, `send` will call the private method and hence a security/encapsulation issue occurs. Whereas `public_send` will only call the method if it is public, otherwise the normal behaviour occurs (calling `method_missing` if overridden, or raising a `NoMethodError`).