# How to pass methods to Ruby Map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following code:

```
wedding = Wedding.where(location_id: user_params[:locationId])
wedding.map(&:guests).each do |member|
  user_ids << member.ids
end
```

In my case `:guests` is a active record table, but I have a couple that I would like to pass thru `map` to generate the `user_ids`

So it would be array of methods like this, that I would like to pass: `[guests, bride, etc etc]`

It would be even better if I could pass the whole array, but otherwise if I can step through the array of methods that would be great too.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm trying this with no luck.. I get: `NameError (wrong constant name guests):`

```
roles = ["guests"]
  wedding = Wedding.where(location_id: user_params[:locationId])
  roles.each do |role|
    clazz = Kernel.const_get(role)
    wedding.map(&:clazz).each do |member|
      user_ids << member.ids
    end
 end
```

Comment: Have you tried the .send method?

Comment: check my answer to see if that works for you

Comment: Can you please explain your schema a bit better? You want to collect all the guests at a wedding location (regardless of the actual wedding?) so you will end up with multiple brides/grooms from different weddings and all the the guests is that the intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, i pass an array of methods to members of the array weddings:

```
weddings = Wedding.where(location_id: user_params[:locationId])

# array with methods you're interested in
methods=[:guests, :bride]

# looping through the weddings array
weddings.each do |wedding|
  
#   looping through the methods array
  methods.each do |method|
    
#     for each wedding, passing every method to the wedding
    members=wedding.public_send(method)
    members.each do |member|
      
#       storing the values
      user_ids << member.ids
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it's better to use `#public_send` instead of `#send` :)

Comment: Oh i see, why is that?

Comment: Here is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152851/4057366) why :)

Comment: Oh i see, so public send is for preservation of encapsulation while send bypasses that. Thanks @AlexGolubenko

Comment: Additionally I would not recommend [`methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-methods) or [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-method) as local variable names since both of these are actually "methods". Furthermore the map process is intensive for the desired result.

Comment: yes you have a point. i actually had some slight discomfort naming them because of the reason you just mentioned. However, i figured in this scenario, it'll help the question author better understand so why not.